# Leaving computer monitor on (not standby) and lit overnight

Tags: power, lcd, energy-saving, monitor-settings

How bad is it to leave an LED monitor lit and on overnight? It will not be in standby mode. The time frame is 6-12 hours of “on”-time, but this could be variable.

To avoid burn in, the brightness and contrast can be turned down so the picture is black, but the LED panel will still be on.

Will this damage the monitor?

Comment: LCD are not really vulnerable to burn in.  If you are concerned you should configure your system to turn your monitors off.

Comment: There are circumstances where the monitor must stay on and cannot be reconfigured otherwise, and this question is geared towards those circumstances.

Comment: They are still not vulnerable to burn in, to clarify your question, how many hours are we talking about specifically? Edit your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: Edited. Also had to correct the original post, this is for an LED monitor, not LCD.

Comment: @JohnA An LED monitor is the same as an LCD monitor, the only difference being that it is backlit by LEDs instead of small light tubes.

Comment: You may try HDMI 1-to-2 which may make your PC not respond to monitor on/off event.

Comment: Is there a reason why it needs to be ON?  Use Windows Power manager to set to a Black screen after 15 to 20 minutes of non-use.